# How to get hyperlink inside iframe

Tags: html

Lets say this is index.html

```
<html>
    ...
    <iframe id="targetid" src="link.com"><iframe>
    ...
</html>
```

and this is link.com

```
<html>
    ...   
    <div class="name" href="http://I_need_this.com">blablbalba<div>
```

I want to get "http://I_need_this.com"

Comment: I wanted to get some links from iframes to get links to my parent web_page

Comment: It would be helpful if you go through the [Question Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and frame your question in a better way to reflect the problem. You can refer [this helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make the parent page script read the href attribute of a link that is inside iframe?!

Comment: خالد محمود YES  thats my prb but i have sovled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the methods below:

```
var div = document.GetElementByClass("name");
var link = div.href;
```

Or:

```
var iframe = document.GetElementById("targetid");
var link = iframe.src;
```

Comment: There is not a method called `GetElementByClass` nor `GetElementById`! you mean `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementById`, note that JavaScript is a cas-sensitive, and **Elements** in first case is plural because it may be more than one element with the same class name.